# why is beveling working differently on these objects?

Tags: modeling

1. so i have these two objects, which are structurally basically the same.
2. If i select the first object, tab into edit mode, select the highlighted edgeloops (shown on the left), and add a bevel with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> with the shown settings, I get the result on the right.
3. Now, if i tab out of edit mode, select the second object, and apply the same procedure with the same settings, I get the result on the right, as you can see, the results are different.
4. Now, in object mode, if I had selected the second object *first* and first object *second*, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to join them, tab into edit mode, and apply the procedure again, I would've gotten this in this case, the result is similar to that of the first object.
5. If i select the second object *first* and first object *second* when joining the objects, the result is reversed:

[image]

Any idea why this is? Both of them are simple objects made using the same procedure.

thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Do both test objects have the same object's scale values?

Comment: As carlo said, make sure the scale is **1**, just apply the scale, with `Ctrl` `A` > *Scale*.

Comment: i feel a bit stupid now. that worked. thanks, guys! :]